# Automating project budgets

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this code in a GAS (Google Apps Script) to automate my project budgets.

Since every project has its own spreadsheet but all functions are in the same script file, being called as a library, I can't use them directly. I need to call `libraryName.functionName`, but it can't serve any arguments unless I do this:

```
function funcoesOrcamento( funcao, args ){
  if(args)
    args = args.split("\!|");
  else
    args = [];

  switch( args.length ){
    case 0:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]();
    case 1:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]( args[0] );
    case 2:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]( args[0], args[1] );
    case 3:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]( args[0], args[1], args[2] );
    case 4:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]( args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] );
    case 5:
      return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ]( args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4] );
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make this more elegant and accept any number of args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` which takes an array of arguments and those arguments will then be passed to the actual function as a series of normal arguments:

```
function funcoesOrcamento( funcao, args ){
  if(args)
    args = args.split("\!|");
  else
    args = [];

  return FuncoesOrcamentoV2[ funcao ].apply(this, args);
}
```

You can read more about `.apply()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Wasn't aware of its existence, THANKS! Also thanks for the english corrections...